# Visual Studio 2017 Published web application returns 500 error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-8.5

I have tried creating a test default net core web application which runs fine with IIS Express on my local machine. When I publish it to the server (Win 2012 R2), it returns a 500 error when I hit the website. Nothing is logged in the Event Log or IIS logs. I've installed the ASP.NET Core Module and restarted the server and still get the error. From what I've read, it's supposed to deploy a testproject.dll and web.config points to that but mine is generating an executable instead and web.config is pointing to that. Everything is in the root of the website as well so I'm not sure what else I can do. I didn't change any code in the test project, just using the default demo app to make sure I can get it running on a server.

Please help!

Comment: Please do take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785773/asp-net-core-app-deployed-on-iis-meets-500-internal-server-error). The key is to first find out what is the reason for the 500 error first.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing, I finally figured out that there was a few error with IIS bindings, and permissions. Now everything is working.

Comment: Care to enlighten further?