# Asp .NET Core on Azure got 502 Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I am having troubles with an asp .net core app deployed on azure.

Azure returns this result:

[image: Result from Azure]

**My question is: How can I debug this? Why is this?/Why this occur? It is a Asp .Net Core problem? A hosting problem?**

I am using web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and this is my Program.cs using `.UseIISIntegration()` and `.UseUrls("http://*:5000")`

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

host.Run();
```

Thanks :)

Comment: check related question [asp.net core app deployed on iis meets 500 internal server error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39786318/2833802). You may start from enabling the `stdouLog`

Comment: Did you find out this? I have the same problem.

Comment: In the first, try enter in azure (kudu) and delete the wwwroot folder or have sure that when you deploy using VS Studio you clean the folder first (delete files), my problem was that I changed my framework and don't cleaned the old publish files

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you can try

1. Check your Logs on Azure (if you enabled logging)
2. Enable Developer exception page by using the `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` & the `app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();` methods in your startup class. This would display the errors, and then you can easily see where the errors are coming from