# Error 500 after upgrade .net core 1.1 prodution application to .net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a relative complex project which is .net core 1.1 (**.net framework**).

The reason why choose .Net Framework was the database is Oracle and the Core Framework didn't support Oracle Entity Data Model. Anyway, the application has been working well in production about a year now.

I am trying to upgrade this project to .net core 2 now. According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x) I modified the Authentication register in Startup, the project compiles.

**old code:**

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "Administration",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/"),
        AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Login/"),
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,                
        AutomaticChallenge = true
     });
```

**updated code:**

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
    services.AddAuthentication("Administration").AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/");
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Login/");
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    });
```

I am getting an error page 500:

[image: Error Image]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Error 500 means internal server error. You should indeed *not* find anything useful on the web part.  You have to check the log of your server.

Comment: I am running this project locally.

Comment: So, check logs of you local machine. If you running with IIS (Express) - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785773/), if you are running with Kestrel only - check console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After look at the stdout log, the problem was ConfigureServices can only take IServiceCollection. I was trying to inject another parameter in, but the project compiled.

### I hope this can be found by intelligent sense or IDE run time