# ASP NET CORE deployment can't access my database on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, database-connection, ubuntu-16.04, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using asp net core 2 developed a web application and deployed in **Ubuntu 16.04** which is running well when I go to browser. Every tabs on my website is working but  when I try to log in with my account it loads for some time and shows error page. I don't know what's wrong here :( I am guessing it is because of I didn't configure **remote connection to Postgresql properly**.

My question is: should I **install Postgresql to my server (which is Ubuntu 16.04) and copy all my data there**? Or should I continue remote connetion to database? What would be a good way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more information about the error. What's the error message? Could you also provide the stack trace of the error?

Comment: @ekad sure. Today I reconfigured my nginx file and launched website again. It's working but when I click to the tab login or register I get error "500 Internal Server Error". Also my log file prints next messages:                                                                                                      
 Jan 16 16:39:37 ok24.kz OK24kz[1462]: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
Jan 16 16:39:37 ok24.kz OK24kz[1462]:  Request finished in 10.4021ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
What am I doing wrong??

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` means an exception happens at runtime, but you still need to find out the real error message. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39785773) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5385714) to get the real error message.