# Error: Failed to load Error - .Net RazorPages - Wrong .Net Version

Tags: c#, .net, razor-pages

I am using a Mac with Apple Silicon. Whenever I click on a page in Azure, I receive an HTTP 500 error. After checking on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785773/asp-net-core-app-deployed-on-iis-meets-500-internal-server-error#comment132941761_54807715), I thought that downloading the file from the [provided link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/2.2) would fix the issue. I downloaded SDK 2.2.207, mac, x64 version. However, I have been coding for so long that I didn't realize I may have downloaded the wrong version.
Now, I am getting this error:

Error: Failed to load A, error: dlopen(/usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/7.0.5/libhostfxr.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/7.0.5/libhostfxr.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/7.0.5/libhostfxr.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/7.0.5/libhostfxr.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

Error: The library libhostfxr.dylib was found, but loading it from /usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/7.0.5/libhostfxr.dylib failed

How can I fix that issue?

I tried to delete wrong version of .net core but I couldn't.